# Android browser scrolling issue

Tags: android, cordova, android-browser

I tried the `Facebooklike plugin` as showed in [Like Box](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/) with android browser using PhoneGap, to my surprise the scroll didn't work at all. No scrollbars appeared and find no way to scroll the contentin webkit.

Anybody tried this, did figure out a solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the like function is about to be deprecated or merged with the share functionality. Try using the share method using facebook's android library http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/#android